# JavaScript loop array: compare previous and next item

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, compare

Loop array and compare the previous item and the next item.

My array:

```
const array = [{id: 1,name: 'A'},{id: 2,name: 'B'},{id: 3,name: 'B'},{id: 4,name: 'B'},{id: 5,name: 'C'},{id: 6,name: 'D'},{id: 7,name: 'E'},{id: 8,name: 'E'},{id: 9,name: 'E'}]
```

My code:

```
let result = []
array.forEach(function(item, index) {
    if (index > 0) {
        if (array[index].name == array[index - 1].name) {
            result.push(array[index - 1].name)
        }
    }
});

console.log('result :', result); // The result I got: [ 'B', 'B', 'E', 'E' ]
```

But I want this result:

```
let result = [ 'B', 'B', 'B', 'E', 'E', 'E' ]
```

Answer (score 1):

In such cases, [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is the key

```
 let result = array.reduce((acc, curr, index) => {
 const previousItem = array[index - 1];
 if (previousItem && curr.name === previousItem.name) {
      acc.push(curr.name);
 }
 return acc;
 }, []);

 console.log(result); // Output: [ 'B', 'B', 'B', 'E', 'E', 'E' ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You just *need* to conditionally check the previous and next value.

```
const array = [{id: 1,name: 'A'}, {id: 2,name: 'B'}, {id: 3,name: 'B'}, {id: 4,name: 'B'}, {id: 5,name: 'C'}, {id: 6,name: 'D'}, {id: 7,name: 'E'}, {id: 8,name: 'E'}, {id: 9,name: 'E'}]
    let result = [];

    array.forEach(function(item, index) {

        let prev = index - 1; // Previous value
        let next = index + 1; // Next value

        if(index > 0) {
            if((array[prev].name == array[index].name) || (array[index].name == array[next].name)) {
                result.push(array[index].name)
            }
        }
    });

    console.log('result: ', result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```js
const array = [
  { id: 1, name: 'A' },
  { id: 2, name: 'B' },
  { id: 3, name: 'B' },
  { id: 4, name: 'B' },
  { id: 5, name: 'C' },
  { id: 6, name: 'D' },
  { id: 7, name: 'E' },
  { id: 8, name: 'E' },
  { id: 9, name: 'E' }
];

const result = [];
let prevName = null;
let count = 0;

array.forEach(item => {
  if (item.name === prevName) {
    count++;
  } else {
    if (count > 1) {
      for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        result.push(prevName);
      }
    }
    prevName = item.name;
    count = 1;
  }
});

if (count > 1) {
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    result.push(prevName);
  }
}

console.log('result:', result);
```